Configure Spring Boot to expose all Actuator endpoints on one port while serving Micrometer metrics on a different port
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I want to achieve the following:
All Actuator endpoints (like /actuator/health, /actuator/info, etc.) should be exposed on the default application port (e.g., 8080).
Micrometer metrics should be served on a separate port (e.g., 8081).
I'm aware that by default, Spring Boot's Actuator and Micrometer metrics are served on the same port, but I'd like to separate them for organizational and security purposes.
So far, I've configured Actuator to use the default application port in application.yml:
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"

And I understand that I can change the management port like this:
management:
  server:
    port: 8081

However, this moves all Actuator endpoints, including metrics, to a different port. What I want is to keep the Actuator endpoints on the default port while serving Micrometer metrics exclusively on another port. Is there a way to configure Spring Boot to achieve this?

There is no built-in feature for this right now, for one, you can open an issue for Spring Boot (but I doubt this will be implemented).
Why do you need metrics on a separate port?
